# Hidden Markov Model Stock Prediction Next Level

Tags: programming, machine-learning, prediction, hidden-markov-model

I was able to fit HMM Model in Python on stocks data. I have completed the training and testing part. The overall fit looks good. However, I have a question, I am not able to predict the next "t+1" move. Can someone help me with how can we predict the next move based on a fitted model? I have read through multiple articles and everyone mentioned trasmat_ but not sure how it'll help.

[image]

Comment: You can't really - you can get the next most likely state, (from the `transmat_` or transition matrix), and from that you can get a probability distribution of the price in that state.

Comment: But really, the point of a HMM is to observe some observable time series $Y_t$, and use that to make inferences about the current state of some  unobservable time series $X_t$.

Comment: @rubikscube09 Thanks for your reply. I have gone through you work on HMM at https://rubikscode.net/2021/09/06/stock-price-prediction-using-hidden-markov-model/ I must appreciate your effort to explain that. In such a scenario how would you extract transmat_ in the work you have done above? Also, What's your thought if we get probability distribution of the price in that state, can we not simulate price to get probable value ?

Comment: No problem, happy to help. A properly estimated HMM will give you a transition matrix (there is most likely some way to  access it in the code), which tells you what the probability is to go from state $i$ today to state $j$ tomorrow. The HMM after observing today's price/returns, will tell you what state you are currently in, and the probabilities of each  state tomorrow.

Comment: @rubikscube09 How can we get probabilities of each state for tomorrow in your piece of work you have done in python? Also, the current probability?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code you've written- I assume you are using `hmmlearn` python package.